# Would a question about aircraft carriers be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I want to ask about aircraft carriers, specifically why they have such huge crews of 5,000+ despite only carrying maybe 100 jets.

I don't know the answer so I don't know if it will turn out to be related to aircraft (maybe they are all mechanics?)

So is it on topic? If not, please point me to the right stack exchange, because I didn't see any obvious one in the list.

Comment: FYI: http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/agency/navy/dept-cvn-72.htm

Answer (score 3):

The crew requirements of naval vessels would not be on topic for an aviation site (even if the primary purpose of that vessel is to launch aircraft).

There is no Stack Exchange site which would be a good fit for this question, However I can tell you that an aircraft carrier is more complicated than a simple runway for launching jets: There are thousands of systems which need to be operated and maintained in order to keep the ship itself functional, and only *then* can it perform its primary mission (for which it carries the air crew & maintenance personnel).